# cucumber step not generating expected text on the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, integration-testing, capybara

I have a step which generates a text line after calculating time differences. The line on the web page looks like "The time difference is 1 hour 20 minutes".
My step definition on the .feature file is as follow:

```
And I should see the time difference is 1 hour 20 minutes
```

My step definition is:

```
And(/^The time difference is (\d+) hours (\d+) minutes$/) do |hr, min|
  expect(page).to have_text(hr)
  expect(page).to have_text(min)
end
```

When I run I get the following error:

```
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected to find text "20" in "bla bla \n\nThe time difference is 0 minutes"
```

The minute part is not properly generating. In the failed screen shot I also see its showing 0 minutes.
Oddly enough if I run the following, The step passes:

```
And(/^The time difference is (\d+) hours (\d+) minutes$/) do |hr, min|
  expect(page).to have_text(hr)
end
```

I tried with have_content as well, but no luck. How can I set the data properly?

TIA

Comment: `have_content` and `have_text` are the same thing they're just aliases of each other, so swapping between them will never make a difference.  I'm guessing the reason your hour check is passing is because you have the number "1" somewhere else on the page.  To make this test worthwhile you really should be doing something like `expect(page).to have_text("The time difference is #{hr} hour #{min} minutes")`.  That will make your test meaningful - to fix why it's failing you're going to need to provide more deatils of the actual cucumber feature, and what the page is doing.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I tried exactly as you mentioned, but still didn't work. The screenshot shows 0 minutes only instead of "xxx hours yyy minutes". In the immediate previous step I have a button click which generates the result. Basically, after I visit the page, I select couple of filters in a form and press a button and it shows the results. Do I have to setup any kind of data for this?

Comment: It was a data issue. I setup the data properly and now my test is passing. Thanks @ThomasWalpole, your suggestion helped me.